# Oracle sql error with to_char function

Tags: sql, oracle

i want to do search depend on date , when i use this statement it gives me empty result

```
Select * from apps.xx_fa_track where TO_CHAR(trx_date, 'mm/dd/yyyy') = '5/25/2014'

Select  to_char(sysdate, 'MM/DD/YYYY') FROM apps.xx_fa_track
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: I suppose `mm` gives you two digits of month (e.g. `05`), and you compare to one-digit month (`5`). When in doubt, `select ... from dual` is your friend, it allows you to evaluate arbitrary expressions and see if they make sense.

Comment: yes thats work , but the problem is in my code i send date in jquery mobile formated like 5/25/2014 !! and i can't change it :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `FM` format modifier to stop the string versrion of the date having leading zeros:

```
where TO_CHAR(trx_date, 'FMmm/dd/yyyy') = '5/25/2014'
```

[SQL Fiddle of the difference](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/30383).

But it's generally better to convert your fixed value to the column's data type:

```
where trx_date = TO_DATE('5/25/2014', 'mm/dd/yyyy')
```

If your `trx_date` includes a time portion you can use a range to cover the whole day, but not sure that's needed here.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that it is better to convert the constant.  However, you might need `trunc(trx_date) = TO_DATE('5/25/2014', 'mm/dd/yyyy')` for the same logic.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should format month in your date with two digits "**05**/25/2014". Like here:

```
Select * from apps.xx_fa_track where TO_CHAR(trx_date, 'mm/dd/yyyy') = '05/25/2014'
```

Comment: yes thats work , but the problem is in my code i send date in jquery mobile formated like 5/25/2014 !! and i can't change it :(